# Possible to send commad over a USB/MSC connection?

Tags: usb, cdc, usb-mass-storage

Is there a way over a USB/MSC connection to signal the USB/MSC device to switch to a different USB protocol such as CDC?

In this case, the USB/MSC device is actually a microprocessor which can already switch from USB/CDC to USB/MSC for a prescribed period of time.  The trick/problem is to correctly guess at the required period of time.  The preferred method would be to stop guessing and simply tell the USB/MSC device it is time to switch to USB/CDC.

Comment: Of course you can design a file format with some commands embedded in it (like the UF2 format which is used for firmware upgrades) and then copy that to the device and have it recognize the commands in the file.  Are you looking for something more elegant though?